# Plotting time series data with ggplot2: group by year and only plot month and day on the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I try to plot a variable `var` measured in two years in a line plot with `ggplot`. Observations from both years should be shown on top of each other in the same panel. In other words: The x-axis should only show information on month and day while year should be used for grouping. My data looks like this:

```r
# libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(date = c(seq(as.Date("2021-06-01"),
                               as.Date("2021-08-01"),
                               by = "1 day"),
                           seq(as.Date("2022-05-15"),
                               as.Date("2022-07-15"),
                               by = "1 day"))) %>%
  mutate(var = sample(1:10, length(date), replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(year = format(date, "%Y"))
```

I currently have this code resulting in a plot with facets per year. However, as mentioned, I want to have the lines for 2021 and 2022 in the same panel.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = var, group = year)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_line(aes(color = year))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's 2 solutions:

#### Fake date

Based on stefan's solution but a bit more generalisable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  mutate(fake_date = make_date(year = min(year(date)), day = day(date), month = month(date))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fake_date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var, col = year))
```

[image]

#### Using a grid of year days

This one involves a simple join onto a full grid of 366 days and
formatting the number scale manually to look like a date.

```r
day_grid <- tibble(day = 1:366)

day_grid %>%
  right_join({
    dat %>%
      mutate(day = yday(date))    
  }, 
  by = "day") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = var)) + 
  geom_line(aes(col = year)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = \(x) format(as_date(x), "%b-%d"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could create a fake date variable where you replace the true year by the same base year, e.g. in the code below I have chosen 2021 as the base year:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

dat <- dat |>
  mutate(
    date1 = if_else(year == 2022, date - lubridate::years(1), date)
  )

ggplot(dat, aes(x = date1, y = var, group = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = year)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks stefan! This certainly generates the desired output. I'll still leave it open for a while to see if anyone can come up with a more elegant solution that works without the fake date variable.